# Prove that solving equation is possible

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**The equation:**

$${2 \over x} + {3 \over y} = {5 \over z} ,\,\,x < z$$

$x,y,$ and $z$ must be natural numbers.

How would I go about proving this equation possible to solve?

I can't seem to figure out how to prove it without doing some "random" calculations to see how numbers fit in the equation.

**Example:**

The variables for the possibly lowest answer is: $$x=1,y=6,z=2$$

Since:
$$
{2 \over 1} + {3 \over 6} = {5 \over 2} ,\,\,1 < 2
$$

How would it be possible to find this answer, or any other correct answer for that matter, without using "random" placeholder variables to see how to equation evolves?

Simpler put: How to is it possible to solve this equation faster and more effectively? Is it possible to determine whether or not the equation is solvable before trying to solve it?

Comment: Essentially you tried $x=1$ and were able to get a solution quickly, so it's hard to argue with success.  Knowing we want $x \lt z$, I thought about making both sides equal to 1, i.e. $z=5$ and finding off the top of my head $x=3$ and $y=9$.  My values $x,y,z$ are bigger, but the equal sides of the equation are smaller than in your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a thought. (Not a very general method, but still useful, I hope.) Rewrite the equation as follows $$\begin{align}\frac3y &= \frac5z - \frac2x\\\frac3y &= \frac{5x-2z}{xz}\\y&=\frac{3xz}{5x-2z}\tag{*}\end{align}$$ Note that in case where $x,z$ are integers such that $5x-2z=1$, we have that $y$ is automatically an integer. But this means that in this case $5x=2z+1$, so $2z+1$ is an odd multiple of $5$. In other words, every solution of $5x=2z+1$ is of the form $$\begin{align}x&=2k+1\\z&=5k+2\end{align}$$ for some integer $k\in\mathbb Z$. Note that $z>x$ iff $k\in\mathbb N_0$. This yields an infinite family of solutions: $$\begin{align}x&=2k+1\\y&=3(2k+1)(5k+2)\\z&=5k+2\end{align}$$ where $k\in\mathbb N_0$ is arbitrary.

In $(*)$ you could also examine $5x-2z=l$ for some other values of $l$, which would yield solutions in case if $3xz$ were divisible by $l$. A particularly nice case to examine would be $5x-2z=3$ in which case, as in the case we examined, this happens automatically. (Other easy cases are $l=-1,-3$, which are the remaining divisors of 3.)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly if $x<z$ then $y>z$.Because if $y<z$,$$\frac{2}{x}+\frac{3}{y}>\frac{2}{z}+\frac{3}{z}=\frac{5}{z}$$Contradiction!

So let $x=z-a$ and $y=z+b$.Plug these values in the equation and you will get,$$z=\frac{5ab}{3b-2a}=\frac{5}{\frac{3}{a}-\frac{2}{b}}$$

Hence minimum value of z can be 5.
Therefore,
$$\frac{3}{a}-\frac{2}{b}=1\implies b=\frac{2a}{3-a}=\frac{2}{\frac{3}{a}-1}$$

The minimum value of $\frac{3}{a}-1$ is 2 (because if $\frac{3}{a}-1=1$ a = 1.5(a fraction))

Hence minimum value of b=2/2=1.$$\frac{3}{a}-1=2\implies a=1$$
So,$$x=z-a=5-1=4$$ $$y=z+b=5+1=6$$

Comment: Why do you say the minimum value of $z$ is $5$?

Comment: Both the OP answer $(x,y,z)=(1,6,2)$ and the answer $(2,12,4)$ have $z<5$ (just to back up Eric's comment). However these are the only two for which $z<5$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach which shows a way to (in theory) obtain all the solutions. We start with your equation [*]: $2/x+3/y=5/z$ and, since your restriction is $x<z$, multiply by $z$ to obtain
$$2\frac{z}{x}+3\frac{z}{y}=5.$$ Not much of a start, but now note that if we define the *rational* variables $s=z/x,\ t=z/y$ we have $$[1]\ \ 2s+3t=5,$$ and our requirement that $x<z$ is now the requirement that $s>1$. Then from $2s+3t=5$ and $t>0$ it follows that also $s<5/2$.

This suggests a procedure: Select any rational number $s \in (1,\frac{5}{2})$. Then define $t=(5-2s)/3$, positive given our restriction on $s$, which makes $[1]$ hold, and in fact we'll have $t \in (0,1).$

But how do we obtain *integer* solutions to [*] from such a rational solution to $[1]$? The idea is to express $s,t$ as fractions $s=a/b,\ t=c/d$ and if it happens that $a \neq c$ we may multiply top and bottom of either or both fractions until they *do* have equal numerators. This is like putting them over a common denominator, but in reverse, we put them under a common numerator. After this adjustment we now have $s=z/x,\ t=z/y,$ and we have not disturbed the requirement $x<z$ since multiplying top and bottom of $s$ by the same natural number preserves that the numerator exceed the denominator. Tracing things back we arrive at a solution to [*]. All primitive solutions arise this way,  and other solutions can be obtained from this by multiplying each of $x,y,z$ by a natural number.